# Necesito algo parecido al subrango (pascal) para usar en C

Tags: c

La duda que tengo es como hago para pasar del siguiente txt:

```
51052
102 Dalmatians
Kevin Lima
Comedy
372
333
6.7
2000
0
Color
1824
```

a una lista simplemente encadenada, específicamente la cuarta linea que es el genero, nos piden que sea un enum, subrango, o algún otro tipo similar excepto String. La duda es que función uso, ya que fgets no funciona en enums.
Esta es la librería de acciones

(básicamente lo que necesitamos hacer es, a partir de un registro para cargar los datos de una película, uno de los datos es el genero, el cual, lógicamente, puede ser varios, (acción, comedia etc) lo que nosotros no sabemos es como lograr que, a partir de la variable Genero poder saber que genero es)

```
#ifndef MOVIEHOUSE_H
#define MOVIEHOUSE_H

#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100

//Registro con informaciÃ³n de una pelicula
// COMPLETAR CON LOS CAMPOS NECESARIOS
typedef enum {Action, Comedy, Adventure, Drama, Horror, SciFi, Fantasy, Animation}Tgenero;
typedef enum {Color, BW}Tcolor;
typedef struct{
char id[15];
char titulo[100];
char director[35];
Tgenero genero;
char likes[10];
char cantidad_votantes[10];
char voto_promedio[5];
char anio[4];
char costo[15];
Tcolor color;
}Movie;


//LSE de Movie
struct Nodo{
Movie pelicula;
struct Nodo *next;
};

//Puntero al primer elemento de la LSE
typedef struct{
struct Nodo *head;
}Lista;

FILE *archivo;
Lista *lista;

//Arreglo de peliculas con cantidad
typedef struct{
Movie peliculas[SIZE];
int cant;
}Arreglo;


/**
Operaciones sobre lista
**/

//Inicializa la lista
void Inicializar(Lista *l);

//Inserta un nodo al comienzo de la lista
void Insertar(Lista *l, Movie a);

//Muestra toda la lista
void MostrarLista(Lista l);

/**
Funcionalidades del proyecto
**/

//Dado un archivo de texto con la informaciÃ³n de las peliculas,
//guarda en la lista todas las pelicuas usando el registro Movie
void DeTxtALista(Lista *l, FILE *f);

//AcciÃ³n que calcula y muestra cuales son las peliculas mas populares
void MasPopulares(Arreglo a);

#endif
```

Comment: Si alguna respuesta soluciona tu problema no olvides marcarla como solución. Te lo comento porque veo que has avanzado con tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es leer ese campo como lo que es actualmente, es decir, una cadena de caracteres, y después programar un algoritmo que a partir de la cadena de caracteres te devuelva el valor del enumerado correspondiente:

```
Tgenero StringToGenero(char const* string)
{
  if( strcmp(string, "Action") == 0 )
    return Action;
  if( strcmp(string, "Comedy") == 0 )
    return Comedy;

  // ...
}
```